# Can the cocos2d Director return time?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ipod-touch

I am currently using the cocos2d Director for controlling my animation with the `pause`, `resume`, and `stopAnimation` methods.  Is it also possible to use the Director to return the time that the animation has played?

I am currently using this method:

```
-(void)stopAnimation:(id)sender {
    //Timer initialized elsewhere: startTimer = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    //Do other method stuff here 

    [[Director sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    stopTimer = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    elapsedTime = (stopTimer - startTimer);
    NSLog(@"elapsedTime = %f", elapsedTime);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through the Director source and didn't see anything that would help you. I did notice that your code, as written, doesn't take into account the time your animation was paused or when other scenes were playing.

If that is a concern you can keep track of the elapsed time in a tick method that you schedule in your Scene or Layer.

MyLayer.h

```
@interface MyLayer : Layer {
  ccTime totalTime;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) ccTime totalTime;
```

MyLayer.m

```
-(id)init 
{
    if( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
    }

    return self;
}

// deltaTime is the amount of running time that has passed
// since the last time update was called
// Will only be called when the director is not paused
// and when it is part of the active scene
-(void)update:(ccTime)deltaTime
{
    totalTime += deltaTime;
}
```